# Is "Must I go" correct?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, questions

I encountered an expression "Must I go?" in my English drill (which is published in Japan).

Is this really correct?  I have never seen "must" in a question.  What I usually see is "Do I have to go?"

Can "must" be used in a question?  If yes, in what situation?  Does it convey a different meaning from "Do I have to"?

I suspect that the drill was written by a Japanese and was not checked by a native speaker.

Am I correct?  Or is the drill correct?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid and common usage. There's a *hint* of formal or polite tone to it, compared to "Do I have to go," but it's not outside of everyday usage.

Comment: You could have found the answer using a dictionary.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh I think you are right and I deleted my comment, thanks; I will think before flagging because I would have to register my account before being able to do so, and also I don't want to be a snitch.

Comment: @BadChad It has nothing to do with being a snitch. If you find it offensive, you write it down, and those comments are only viewable to the moderators, who I must say, will take due action, quite without a bias.

Comment: Related but probably not a duplicate: ["must" vs "have to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27014/9161)

Answer (score 4):

Using 'must' in that way is completely normal in English. It is slightly more formal than using 'have to'.

> **must**
>
> **modal verb**
>
> used to show that it is necessary or very important that something
> happens in the present or future:
>
> *Meat must be cooked thoroughly.*
>
> *I must get some sleep.*
>
> *You mustn't (or must not) show this letter to anyone else.*
>
> *Luggage must not be left unattended* (= it is against the rules).
>
> *Must you leave so soon?*
>
> *"Must I sign this?" "Yes, you must."*

[Must (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/must)

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle differences between *"must"* and *"have to"* in the first person. Sometimes, using one instead of another seems unnatural, but in informal writing/speech it is not a mistake to use one instead of another. Both express obligation, but *"must"* is more appropriate if the obligation is more subjective (one feels that it is necessary to do), for example:

> I must tell you something because it is important for me that you know about it.

or it is an obligation made in a written rules or instructions:

> According to the safety guidelines, I must refrain from eating and drinking in the lab.

while *"have to"* is more appropriate if the obligation is due to objective, more general and/or external circumstances (another person in the position of authority tells you that it is necessary to do, and/or the general situation makes it so it is necessary to do):

> I have to fill the paperwork tomorrow because the deadline is coming soon.

---

If we want to use a specific example where the only one difference is the verb being used, then:

> I must write a letter to Karen.

if I just realized that I haven't seen Karen for twenty years and I wonder what she's up to, and I decided it is appropriate to let her know I wish her all the best; and

> I have to write a letter to Karen.

if I just found out that Karen is commercially using my music without my permission, and my lawyer tells me it is the appropriate time for a cease-and-desist letter.

---

It is rare to see *"must I ...?"* because *"must"* is usually used in case of obligations you made on your own to yourself, so there is usually no need to ask yourself about what you already know (because you came up with it in the first place).

Also, the verb *"must"* can only be used to express present obligations, while *"have to"* can be used to express past, present, as well as future obligations, making *"have to"* more flexible in usage.

In general, I don't think the drill is incorrect; in many situations these two verbs are interchangeable, and the difference between them is subtle. *"Have to"* is more informal, while *"must"* is used more in formal and official writing.

Comment: Hey there. Welcome to ELL, and thanks for contributing. Could you elaborate a little on what exactly do you intend as subjective and objective? I must confess I am a little confused by the comparative usage you have put forward.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Hey, thanks for welcome, I had the feeling that they could be confusing, sorry about that, I am still researching and thinking about the answer with the goal of expanding and making it more clear, the current version is just a prototype I am gradually upgrading.

Comment: Cool with me. I will come back again sometime to check the updated version. Good luck!

Comment: You do see some "Must I...?" questions in literary or poetic usage, similar to "Shall I...?"

Comment: @Kevin I don't know, I don't even remember the last time I have had any sort of English literature in my hand, sorry bro :D but in common informal experience, I don't remember hearing/seeing "Must I ..."? anywhere.